# Using NoSQL on data with few relations

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, database, nosql

I'm currently planning the development of a service which should handle a fair amount of request and for each request do some logging.
Each log will have the following form

```
{event: "EVENTTYPE", userid: "UID", itemid: "ITEMID", timestamp: DATETIME}
```

I expect that a lot of writing will be done, while reading and analysis will only be done once per hour.

A requirement in the data analysis is that I have to be able to do the following query:
Are both events, A and B, on item (ITEMID) logged for user (UID)? (Maybe even tell if event A came before event B based on their timestamps)

I have thought about MongoDB as my storage solution.

- Can the above query be (properly) carried out by the MongoDB aggregation framework?
- In the future I might add on to the analysis step, with a relation from ITEMID to ITEM.Categories (I have a collection of items, and each item has a series of categories). Possibly it would be interesting to know how many times event A occured on items grouped by the individual items category, during the last 30 days. Will MongoDB then be a good fit for my requirements?

Some information about the data I'll be working with:
I expect to be logging in the order of 10.000 events a day on average.
I haven't decided yet, whether the data should be stored indefinitely.

- Is MongoDB a proper fit for my requirements? Is there another NoSQL database that will handle my requirements better? Is NoSQL even usable in this case or am I better off sticking with relational databases?
- If my requirement of the frequency of analysis changes, say from once an hour to real time. I believe Redis would serve my purpose better than MongoDB, is this correctly understood?

Comment: You have good intentions here but your overall question(s) are way too broad. Can you possibly narrow this down to something specific that is more suitable to a single answer? That is generally what is required of this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are both events, A and B, on item (ITEMID) logged for user (UID)? (Maybe even tell if event A came before event B based on their timestamps)
>   Can the above query be (properly) carried out by the MongoDB aggregation framework?

Yes, absolutely.  You can use the `$group` operator to aggregate events by ITEMID, UID, you can filter results before the grouping via `$match` to limit them to a specific time period, or with any other filter, and you can push times (first, last) of each type of event into the document that the `$group` operator creates.   Then you can use `$project` to create a field indicating what came before what, if you wish.

All of the capabilities of aggregation framework are well outlined here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/

> In the future I might add on to the analysis
>   step, with a relation from ITEMID to ITEM.Categories (I have a
>   collection of items, and each item has a series of categories).
>   Possibly it would be interesting to know how many times event A
>   occured on items grouped by the individual items category, during the
>   last 30 days. Will MongoDB then be a good fit for my requirements?

Yes.  Aggregation in MongoDB allows you to `$unwind` arrays so that you can group things by categories, if you wish.  All of the things you've described are easy to accomplish with aggregation framework.

Whether or not MongoDB is the right choice for your application is outside the scope of this site, but you the requirements you've listed in this question can be implemented in MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you, Asya. This is definitely gonna help me.